# Fill DataGridView RowHeader from SqlDataAdapter

Tags: vb.net

I have basic configuration in binding database table with 3 columns to datagridview.

```
Dim ds = New DataSet
Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select first, second, third from mytable")
    da.Fill(ds)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

This brings data to datagridview columns.

Question is how can I get data (integer) from 'first' column of 'mytable' to be showed in rows headers instead of first column of datagrid?

Comment: Check this link: http://www.vb-tips.com/PaintRowHeader.aspx

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, thats interesting. But that enumerate rows by rowindex not by value from database. Looking as that don't seem simple maybe will be 'cheaper' to just hide row headers.